# Audio library "soundbank-deluxe.gm": how to find the tuplet "instrument/program number"?

Tags: java, midi

I am doing a "free-to-chose project" as an homework, and I decided to do kind of a piano. To play the sounds, I use the MIDIchannel with "soundbank-deluxe.gm". As this is something I never did before, I went looking for a tutorial and I ended up on the following code:

```
      // global variables
      private MidiChannel channel;
      private Synthesizer synthesizer;

      // in constructor
      channel = synthesizer.getChannels()[0];
      channel.programChange(0); // this corresponds to PIANO
```

It appears that the value 0 corresponds to the Piano in this soundbank. 26 is the guitare and 16 the orgue... frankly I do not need anything else, but out of curiosity I went looking for a "map" to find out which other instruments I could have played... but I couldn't find it!

Does anybody know where I could find the correspondences instrument/program nuber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think i found out the solution. The tuples are not dependent form the library but from the MIDI itself. I think what I had to look for was "MIDI numbers".